# Not getting results for Top n records from group in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have one table table1
from that i need to show top 5 OS based on the highest counts
i need to group them on three columns os,device,model

When i  executed below query I didnt get any result.
Whats wrong in the below query?

```
SELECT * FROM
     (SELECT distinct os, count,
     DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY os ORDER BY count DESC)rn
     FROM (Select os ,device,model,SUM(cal_count) as count
     from table1
     group by os,device,model)b ) a
     WHERE a.rn = 5
     ;
```

Comment: I will be more direct than @Gordon below: **_A_** your ranking is done for each OS and ranks the combinations [Device,Model] as aggregated in the sub-query, so each OS value will have 1..N ranks attached **_B_** you want "all things with rank 1 to 5" but your query reads "only things with rank 5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the query like this:

```
select t.*
from (select os, device, model, SUM(cal_count) as cnt,
             dense_rank() over (partition by os order by sum(cal_count) desc) as seqnum
      from table1
      group by os, device, model
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```

As I understand your query, it would only return the 5th row for each group.  Perhaps there is some sort of error.